# S3 upload fails in some Mobile Network using S3 JavaScript SDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I notice that in some Mobile Network Upload to S3 fails even if the connection is good. But When I switch to another Mobile Network then it works. I am using S3 JavaScript SDK and multipart upload. Am I missing anything? Is it because the IP Address gets changed frequently in Mobile Network?

Thanks